# Gitlab Runner - HELM - ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Tags: gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm deploying a HELM chart using:

> helm upgrade -i -f < RELEASE PARAMETERS >

When I run this locally in a custom docker image, the release works fine.

When I try to run the same release using the GilabRunner (self-hosted runners) I'm getting this error:

> ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

More details:

> HELM Version:
>
> > version.BuildInfo Version:"v3.5.0"

> Kubectl Version:
>
> > Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.2", GitCommit:"52c56ce7a8272c798dbc29846288d7cd9fbae032", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-04-16T11:56:40Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

> Gitlab Runner Version:
>
> > Version:     13.2.2

---

Add more information
The output from --debug from gitlab-runner

> Executing "step_script" stage of the job script  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Looking for image index.docker.io/repository...  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Removing container runner-runner_id-project-project_id-concurrent-0-e6d1019ef7fea87c-build-2  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id
> Disconnecting container runner-runner_id-project-project_id-concurrent-0-e6d1019ef7fea87c-build-2 from networks  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id
> Removing container runner-runner_id-project-project_id-concurrent-0-e6d1019ef7fea87c-build-2 finished with error Error: No such container: runner-runner_id-project-project_id-concurrent-0-e6d1019ef7fea87c-build-2 (docker.go:845:0s)  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Creating container runner-runner_id-pro

> job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Attaching to container container_id ...  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Starting container container_id ...  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Appending trace to coordinator... ok                code=202 job=job_id job-log=0-2763 job-status=running runner=runner_id sent-log=894-2762 status=202 Accepted update-interval=3s

> Executing build stage                               build_stage=after_script job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Skipping stage (nothing to do)                      build_stage=after_script job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Executing build stage                               build_stage=upload_artifacts_on_failure job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Skipping stage (nothing to do)                      build_stage=upload_artifacts_on_failure job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Skipping referees execution                         job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> WARNING: Job failed: exit code 1                    duration=7.163806778s job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Appending trace to coordinator... ok                code=202 job=job_id job-log=0-3369 job-status=running runner=runner_id sent-log=2763-3368 status=202 Accepted update-interval=3s

> Submitting job to coordinator... ok                 code=200 job=job_id job-status= runner=runner_id

> Removing container container_id  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Disconnecting container container_id from networks  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Removing container container_id_2  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Disconnecting container container_id_2 from networks  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Removing container container_id_3  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Disconnecting container container_id_3 from networks  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Removed container container_id_3  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Removed container container_id  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> Removed container container_id_2  job=job_id project=project_id runner=runner_id

> WARNING: Failed to process runner                   builds=0 error=exit code 1 executor=docker runner=runner_id

Comment: Can you run with `--debug` param to print debug information?

Comment: I add the output in the question =)

Comment: No, I mean adding `debug` to `helm` command

Comment: helm.go:65: [debug] stat /root/.config/helm/registry.json: not a directory
/root/.config/helm/registry.json
github.com/deislabs/oras/pkg/auth/docker.NewClient
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/deislabs/oras@v0.8.1/pkg/auth/docker/client.go:28
helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/experimental/registry.NewClient
/home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/internal/experimental/registry/client.go:70
main.newRootCmd
/home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/cmd/helm/root.go:156
main.main
/home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/cmd/helm/helm.go:63
runtime.main
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:204
runtime.goexit

Comment: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374

Comment: Here is the error: `stat /root/.config/helm/registry.json: not a directory /root/.config/helm/registry.json`. Is there any problem with your config or permission?

Comment: I'm running the command as root

Comment: What are your parameters in `helm`?

Comment: helm list or helm upgrade -i -f values-env.yaml -f secrets.yaml --set tag=tag --namespace namespace --wait --force --timeout 120s

Answer (score 0):

The main issue for this error is related to a previous step is creating a file under /root/.config

When I identify it, I set the `--registry-config=~/.helm_config/helm/registry.json` in the helm command and the issue was solved.